# How to add new menu in multi level menu sidebar PHP?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this sidebar menu like this

[image]

I want to add new menu either it Parent Menu or Sub Menu, but I have the problem,
there is same menu name like 'Tahun 2019' from 'Risalah Keuangan with 'Tahun 2019' from 'Rapat/Sidang'.
I don't know how to properly make the form to input the new menu because the same menu name.

This is my current Add Menu form,

[image]

The first field is to enter the Menu Name
Second field is to choose the parent of the menu.
How can i distinguish the same menu?

Comment: no idea we since you didnt give us any code

Comment: You could not sort the second dropdown but instead show the actual menu structure

Comment: cant really understand what you want. you want to avoid duplicate? or you want the possibility to add duplicate

Comment: I edited the second pic, as you can see there is a lot of menu with the same name, e.x : Tahun 2017
When i want to add new menu, i can't which parent menu is right because the same name

Answer (score 0):

I would output the full path instead... Something like

Rapat/Sidang --- Tahun 2019

Risalah Keuangan --- Tahun 2019

Etc